# How to grab an objects property that is stored in an array on a click event

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, createjs

I have this Object and I spawn it onto the canvas after one is picked and pushed into my array.

```
 function grabObjProp(){
    var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    goodProp = {};
        goodProp["name"] = "goodguy";
        goodProp["MC"] = new lib.goodObj();

    badProp = {};
        badProp["name"] = "badguy";
        badProp["MC"] = new lib.badObj();

    if(randomInt < 7)
        ObjArray.push(goodProp);
    else
        ObjArray.push(badProp);

    createObj();
}
```

I then run an if/else to see if I am clicking the good or the bad and based off that I then either run a gameOver function or I continue the game. My current issue is that my if/else checks the last array that was added and if I badguy is added when I click a goodguy the condition is met and the game ends. I wanted to know how to get the name of the object I clicked store it to a variable then compare that variable when I click and object.

```
function Click(e){

    if(ObjArray[ObjArray.length - 1].name != "goodguy"){
        addGameOverScreen();
    }else{
        numClicked +=1;
        scoreTxt.text = numClicked;
        exportRoot.removeChild(e.currentTarget);
        grabObjProp();
    //}
}
```

Edit** added -1 to `if(ObjArray[ObjArray.length].name != "goodguy")`so that the if was always check the last index of the array.

Comment: May I ask you something? If you have an array of say, three elements [1, 2, 3], the length is 3, but there is no index 3. The greatest index is 2. Am I missing something?  Then, how this condition could NOT be met? I mean, if the array is of a length of 3 elements, Array[3] will be undefined, therefore the "name" property will never be equal to "goodguy"
Im speaking about this line specifically:
if(ObjArray[ObjArray.length].name != "goodguy")

Please sorry my bad english.

Comment: What elements are you clicking on? Do they somehow correspond/map to `ObjectArray`. This is not at all clear from the question.

Comment: @trincot I am clicking on the good and bad guy objects which are pushed into an array i.e (ObjArray) which then another function adds the last index of the array to the screen and gives it the event listener. I then check in that event listener if the last obj in the array != "goodguy" mean if it is it will run an else that continues the game, but I found out that if it adds the badguy when I go to click on the goodguy it runs the condition because the last index of the array is now "badguy" which is not good so it becomes true then. Sorry if this confuses you I was never good at explaining.

Comment: Hold on, you push plain JavaScript objects to `ObjArray`, which have two properties. Plain objects are just memory thingies, they are not visible, let be clickable, so you must be talking about something else? HTML elements? Can you add the HTML in that case? Is the `lib` producing HTML elements? Too many unknowns to answer this question...